# Why is Win10 1909 forcing a feature update on me?

Tags: windows-10

My understanding was that Win10 now only forces a feature update when your current build is getting close to its end of service life?

Yet I am getting daily nag messages and suspect that 20h2 has already been downloaded (can't think of why else my C: partition has suddenly lost around 20 GB of free space))

So why is it doing this now, so early? Surely 1909 has another six months of life left?

Is there any way to tell Win10 that I would prefer to wait for 21h1, which after all should be out before end of 1909's support?

Comment: If the update download is complete (appears to be) then it will be in a pending update state and you should let that happen. Nothing gained by waiting and other updates (other apps) may not happen until the pending update is complete.

Answer (score 1):

> So why is it doing this now, so early? Surely 1909 has another six months of life left?

Windows 10 version 2004 is considered stable. There are no know issues with 2004 nor 20H2 at this time[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1506475/windows-10-1903-missing-deferment-feature-and-quality-update-option)

> Is there any way to tell Win10 that I would prefer to wait for 21h1, which after all should be out before the end of 1909's support?

Since you are still on `Windows 10 version 1909` you can use a group policy to prevent the installation of a feature update for 365 days.

This option also can be controlled within the Settings UWP application.

[image]

You can also control this behavior by setting **DeferFeatureUpdatesPeriodInDays** within `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings` to the number of days you want to defer the update (maximum 365 days).

[image]

> [image]

Image Source: [Here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24157-windows-update-defer-feature-quality-updates-windows-10-a.html)